# Highcharts: Is there a way to show connecting lines on Waterfall chart having few null data values?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, waterfall

On Highcharts version 10.3.3, if waterfall chart is plotted on data containing few null values, connecting lines are not shown for all valid cases.

Demo:

Connecting lines Issue on v10.3.3 : https://jsfiddle.net/rxq4vznj

Please refer the following series object:

```
"series": [{
      "zIndex": 1,
      "internalName": "UntitledCube4_UntitledCube4_ID_1_msr",
      "type": "waterfall",...
```

Please suggest a fix for this issue.

Comment: Since this has been fixed in the newer version, I would suggest updating the library. It doesn't look like it can be fixed with a simple workaround.